# MySQL - nothing happens when I´m trying to update the table

Tags: php, mysql

I´m new at PHP/MySQL, so please bear with me on this one. :)

First, my database table(stamps) look like this:
http://jello.dk/db.png

The case: I´m trying to update the column "value" to "2" if the "stamptype" is set to "900".

I can´t get this to work:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","Test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
    $sql = "UPDATE stamps SET value = '2' WHERE stamptype = '900';";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: `mysql` !== `mysqli`: don't mix and match

Comment: why are you mixing mysql and mysqli. better use mysqli version only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct way

**Replace**

```
 $sql = "UPDATE stamps SET value = '2' WHERE stamptype = '900';";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

**With**

```
 $sql = "UPDATE stamps SET value = '2' WHERE stamptype = '900'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to make a query using the `mysql_` library but you haven't opened a connection with it. You've opened a connection with the `mysqli_` library.

Pick either `mysqli_` or `mysql_` (or PDO) and stick to it. Don't switch database libraries mid-script. (Don't pick `mysql_`, it is deprecated).

Comment: This is a great comment, but I'm not really sure it counts as an answer...

Comment: @JanDvorak - I think this is a good answer. Needs a tweak about using `else` in the `if` statement

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks for the lesson. It didn´t answer my question, but good to know.

Comment: @DaneFromTheNorth — Err… it did answer the question. You just accepted an answer that expressed this in code with no explanation.

Comment: @Quentin: Sorry, my bad!